# SSAS MDX YTD Last Value only

Tags: ssas, mdx

Please could you assist:

fact table
a) Actuals

Measure: Weekly Inflow this is the field within the underlying database table 
[Measures].[Weekly Inflow]

I calculate YTD Inflow using the following

Aggregate
(
  PeriodsToDate
  (
     [Period End].[Period End].[Year],
     [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember
  ),
  [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow]
)

I want to display a new calculated measure which will show me a single YTD Inflow value only for the very last record where an actual inflow is shown.
This must not be repeated as a running total just a single value. Please see the example attached:
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z3Zm.jpg)
How can i achieve this using a calculated measure? Please could you provide an example?

Date dimension: [See screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjZcb.jpg)

Please see screen shot 3 after adding the MDX. The values with the pink background should not be shown. Those with a green background need to be presented:[Screen Shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnukL.jpg)

Screen shot 4: [Additional Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5usHX.jpg)

Screen shot 5: [Screen shot 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG1ZA.jpg)

[Screen Shot 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcaiB.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to run BottomCount (1 row) on your [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] to get the last tuple that has a non null value of _Weekly Inflow,this will be a calculated measure .Next, in your YTD measure add a case that checks the current value of the  [Period End].[Period End] user hierarchy to the only value of the above measure. I dont have a sample cube at hand but the query structure will be like below.

```
 with member Measures.[NewColumn]
as 
(bottomcount(
nonempty(
existing
{([Date].[Date].[Date].members)}
,[Measures].[_Weekly Inflow]),
1
).item(0).Name

member 
Measures.[YTD]
as 
case when [Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=Measures.[NewColumn] then 
Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
else 
null end
```

Edit

```
with member Measures.[NewColumn]
    as 
    (bottomcount(
    filter(
    existing
    {([Date].[Date].[Date].members)}
    ,[Measures].[_Weekly Inflow]>0),
    1
    ).item(0).Name

    member 
    Measures.[YTD]
    as 
    case when [Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=Measures.[NewColumn] then 
    Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
when 
[Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=[Period End].[Period End].defaultmember then Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
    else 
    null end
```

Edit

```
    member 
    Measures.[YTD]
    as 
    case when [Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=Measures.[NewColumn] then 
    Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
when 
[Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name="Feburary 2018" then Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
    else 
    null end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188447/discussion-on-answer-by-moazrub-ssas-mdx-ytd-last-value-only). Please remember to [edit] any important information into the answer.

Comment: @MoazRub: Still having an issue with this: Grand Total is blank when i remove February 2018 and replace it with: 
case when [Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=Measures.[NewColumn] then 
    Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
when 
[Period End].[Period End].currentmember.level.name = [Measures].[NewColumn]

then Aggregate ( PeriodsToDate ( [Period End].[Period End].[Year], [Period End].[Period End].CurrentMember ), [Measures].[_Weekly Inflow] )
    else 
    null end

Comment: @MoazRub: The Measures.[NewColoumn] holds '2018-02-11' and not February 2018. I believe this is the issue. Would i need to replace Measures.[NewColumn] within the following statement:  case when [Period End].[Period End].currentmember.name=Measures.[NewColumn] ? Thank you

Comment: Yes that is what you need to do

Comment: @MoazRub: Thank you. I found a situation where this might not be accurate. Please see screen shot  6. Would the NewColumn calculated measure need to be amended? When there are multiple weekly inflow values, we only want the very last YTD values to be shown (highlighted in green). Happy with the grand total here.